# (Polymorphism) Addition parameter pass to constructor of derived class in factory pattern

Tags: oop, design-patterns, polymorphism, factory-pattern

In factory pattern, we use a `Factory` class to produce a `Product` class that implement `Abstract Product`.

```
interface AbstractProduct {
     public string getDetail();
}

class Product_A : AbstractProduct {
     public string getDetail();
}

class Product_B : AbstractProduct {
     public string getDetail();
}

class Factory {
     public AbstractProduct produce(int product_id){
          if (product_id == 1){
                return Product_A();
          }
          else if (product_id == 2){
                return Product_B();
          }
     }
}

int main() {
     Factory factory = new Factory();
     int id; // a random number either 1 or 2

     print(factory.produce(id).getDetail());
}
```

My question is, what if today we need extract information to pass into `Product_B` from `main()`, for example a reference of a class instance.

```
int main() {
     // object that need to be passed into Product_B
     Database database = new Database();

     Factory factory = new Factory();
     int id; // a random number either 1 or 2

     print(factory.produce(id).getDetail());
}

class Product_B : AbstractProduct {
     public string getDetail() {
         // I need the reference of database here.
         // I'm unable to instance a database in side Product_B.
         // I need to somehow pass it into Product_B.
         database.query();
     }
}
```

The only solution come to my mind is...

```
class Factory {
     // pass the reference here
     public AbstractProduct produce(int product_id, Database db){
          if (product_id == 1){
                return Product_A();
          }
          else if (product_id == 2){
                return Product_B(db);
          }
     }
}
```

Is there any good solution or relative design pattern can solve this problem **Elegant** and **Clean** ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Instead of passing a product_id to your 'produce' method, you could pass an object that is polymorphic. Let's say the base class of that object only contains the product_id, but then you could subclass it and potentially add parameters to it based on your use-case.

Comment: @AlexG, thanks for your comment. But what is the different between this method and pass (product_id, db). Because the `Factory` return `Product` mostly base on product_id, and sometime it need additional information, say db, and I don't know when will it be required. So how can I determine whether to pass `BaseClass` with product_id or `DeriveClass` with (product_id, db)?

Comment: I have no idea of your use-case, but it feels like if you need to add parameters or do a bunch of conditional stuff, then the factory pattern isn't the right choice. My approach was to provide a single function signature and be able to pass in different parameters, which implies the caller knows a few things about what will be instantiated.

Comment: My detail use-case is that I'm working MVC web page where I need to process data from a row of database column (e.x. GET ? product_id=1). Because I need to use different strategy to process the data base on product_id, so I pass product_id to a `Factory` and get relevant class to process it. However, during some special product, I need to query more data from database, so I need the reference of $this->db from Codeigniter controller to pass to the derive object that produce by `Factory`

Answer (score 0):

The downside with your solution is that, every client of the `Factory` must have a `Database` in order to call the `produce` method.

So you can use the `Abstract Factory` pattern here:

```
interface AbstractFactory {
    AbstractProduct produce();
}

class Factory_A implements AbstractFactory {
    AbstractProduct produce() { return new Product_A(); }
}

class Factory_B implements AbstractFactory {
    private Database db;
    public Factory_B(Database db) { this.db = db; }
    AbstractProduct produce() { return new Product_B(db); }
}

class Client {
    private AbstractFactory factory;
    public Client(AbstractFactory factory) { this.factory = factory; }
    public void foo() {
        AbstractProduct product = factory.produce();
        // ...
    }
}

void main() {
    AbstractFactory factory = random() == 1 ?
                                new Factory_A() :
                                new Factory_B(new Database(...));

    print(factory.produce().getDetail());

    Client client = new Client(factory);
    client.foo();
}
```

Hope this helps.